# Ubuntu 14.04 black screen without login after switching GPU to NVIDIA using prime-indicator

Tags: boot, nvidia, xorg, indicator, nvidia-prime

After installation of prime-indicator for NVIDIA, I tried to switch from Intel to NVIDIA. (I also have nvidia-prime installed.) System rebooted, started to load, but never got to login screen. It just froze with a black screen and a "_" symbol in the first line of it.
I was able to get into console in system recovery mode using GRUB menu, but removing prime-indicator, reinstallation of nvidia-"everything" and rebooting did nothing.

However, when I select previous Linux kernel in GRUB to boot in normal mode, it loads relatively well. (Although, it does not show no side panel or programs for first 10 or so seconds.)
After several minutes in the session, a message about system problem appears, saying that there was a problem with xorg.

I don't want to make any more mess in the system, so I didn't run any install/reinstall/purge commands in the session with previous kernel yet. 
My system was running quite well for months before, and I'd like it to do it again...

Answer (score 0):

Try with bumblebee instead https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa Also please post more information next time e.g. your GPU model :P